# Mostrar conteúdo de um arquivo abrindo o arquivo com a string de conteudo de uma variável

Tags: linux, terminal, shell-script

Estou com um problema para mostrar o conteúdo de um arquivo utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
variavel="Affonso\,\ I.\ P..txt"
cat < "$variavel"
```

E executando o mesmo comando no terminal mas sem usar variável, ele funciona normalmente como a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso arrumar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
variavel="$(< Affonso\,\ I.\ P..txt)"

echo "$variavel"
```

Comment: eu tentei com esse seu trecho de código mas infelizmente manteve a msg de erro: ./show_var_arq.sh: linha 3: Affonso\,\ I.\ P..txt: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Comment: eu consegui fazer funcionar parcialmente, agora deu um problema que ele perdeu as quebras de linha do texto original.

Comment: variavel= ` cat < Affonso\,\ I.\ P..txt ` 

echo $variavel

Comment: @AGPC Atualizei a resposta, veja se agora funciona.